# jquery form validation with tabs and custom error messaging

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using the http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ for form validation.

My form is split into various tabs.

The last tab is where my form submission button is. Now the validation checks seem to work, however, the validation always goes back to a field that's missing for completion.

I would rather just output my error message above the submit button telling the user to go back to the tab in question and complete the field.

Here's the code I'm using

```
var errcontainer = $('.errcontainer');
$("#application-submit").click(function() {
        $("#application-form").validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            student_lastname: "required"
        },
        errorContainer: errcontainer,
        errorLabelContainer: $("ol", errcontainer),
        wrapper: 'li',
        meta: "validate"
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F2HNh/

The error message is output when I disable the tabs but when I enable them, I get nothing.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like any other jQuery plugin, you would initialize it on DOM ready.  There is no need to put [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) inside of a click handler.  If you just want it to test the form's validity on the submit button click, it already does that by default.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#application-form").validate({
        debug: true, // <-- this will block a real submission
        rules: {
            student_lastname: "required"
        },
        errorContainer: errcontainer, // <-- errcontainer not defined or a valid selector.
        errorLabelContainer: $("ol", errcontainer), // <-- errcontainer not defined or a valid selector.
        wrapper: 'li',
        meta: "validate"  // <-- this is not a documented option
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what you intended with `meta: "validate"`... [it's not a documented option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

Also, your `errorContainer:` and `errorLabelContainer:` options are not valid.  [As per the documentation and examples](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), `errorLabelContainer:` is *"as specified by the selector passed as `errorContainer` option"*.  `errcontainer` is not a valid selector, nor is it a defined variable.

Same thing with `errorLabelContainer:`, `$("ol", errcontainer)` is not a valid selector.

Both of those options, as you've defined them, cause the plugin to fail with errors:  http://jsfiddle.net/5JRNV/

If you don't want to focus on the first invalid field, use the `focusInvalid: false` option.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#application-form").validate({
        focusInvalid: false,
        rules: {
            student_lastname: "required"
        },
        // other options.
    });
});
```

**Standard Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/5G5PT/**

Comment: Thanks Sparky. I was only focusing on the core code I was using in the fiddle. Doc ready is wrapped and I'm also declaring errcontainer elsewhere in the JS. The reason for the click event check is that there is also an 'application save' button which submits the form also and I don't want validation at that point. Meta was used here jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html - the validation works as I'd expect when not using the tabs though.

Comment: @StevenGrant, again, `.validate()` is **not** a "check"; it's the plugin's initialization routine.  To do a check on demand, you'd use `.valid()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the *ignore* option with an empty array

```
$('form').validate({
 // your other options    
 ignore:[]
});
```

If the error messages are showing in your *errorLabelContainer* before you enable tabs, but are not showing afterwards then it could be because the the errors are on fields that are hidden, which are not validated by default.